# Нужно динамически добавить форму yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, yii, activeform

Есть скрипт который берет `Ajax-ом` из странички форму `activeRecord`  и  уставляет ее методом `html()`, но потом ее jq валидация не работает. Можно ли как нибудь добавить поля в форму или динамически добавить всю форму `Ajax-ом`

Comment: С формой идет js с валидацией, скорее всего у Вас его не хватает

Comment: @robertobadjo идет файлом? Если да, то как называется ?

Comment: Не файлом, на страницу генерируется js в зависимости от формы

Comment: Откройте любую форму на yii и увидите js с валидацией

Comment: @robertobadjo Спасибо за ответ, вы были правЫ!)